# Flattening a map into a list of records

Tags: java, collections, lambda

In my everyday work I'm trying to move away from traditional iterating over collections to a more Java 8 streams-like behavior. I'm currently working on a project where I have a collection defined as:

```
Map<String, <Int, String>> lineBufferMap;
```

that I would like to iterate through and produce a `List<Record>`.

My current implementation goes something like this:

```
Set<Record> l = lineBufferMap
    .entrySet().stream()                                            
    .flatMap(outer -> e.getValue()
            .entrySet().stream()                                    
            .map(inner -> createRecord(outer.getKey(), inner.getKey(), inner.getValue())))                                                             
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

`createRecord` method:

```
private Record create(String filename, Long lineNumber, String line) {
    Record record = null;
    try {
        record = new Record(
                offsetKey(key),
                offsetValue(lineNumber),
                topic,
                keySchema,
                keyStructBuilder.withContent(line).buildStruct(),
                valueSchema,
                valueStructBuilder.withContent(line).buildStruct());
    }catch (ParseException e){
        log.error("Malformed line",e);
    }
    return record;
}
```

I'm not happy with `.filter(Object::nonNull)` and haven't come up with a better idea yet.

To add to this problem, the `createStruct` methods can produce an unchecked parse-exception which in the current solution aborts the whole iteration.

I would prefer it to not break the whole iteration but just to skip the current faulty line and continue with the rest.

This could be considered overcomplicating things as someone suggested but I'm mostly doing it for educational purposes.

Comment: Why would you use forEach here? It only makes it harder.

Comment: Well, its sort of the best i could come up with. What would you suggest?

Comment: Plain old for loops? Using streams for the sake of using streams should not be your goal  .

Comment: Well in this case is sort of is - for educational purpose :-/

Comment: What do you mean by "something _like_"? Is this your real code? Also please show the `Record()` constructor, so that we can understand the error handling.

Comment: @200_success The Record is just a POJO with little functionality. The error handling is basically just a catch-block surrounding the source-snippet in my first post. If a line is mallformed the whole iteration will break and no Records will be collected.

Comment: Please show that then.

Comment: possible bug in the EDIT part: if you call `.filter(Objects::isNull)`, the resulting stream will contain only `null`s, which is hopefully not what you expect. It should be `.filter(Objects::nonNull)`.

Comment: True @Antot. In my working, unoptimized, version i had obj ->!obj.isNull and when i transfered that here the ! was lost and... yeah you get the picture. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: ... So you should change it, because right now this isn't working like it should.